# I cannot get my joins to work on a some tables, but they will work on others. Trying to select columns from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, left-join, inner-join

[image: ERD]

I am new to mySQL so sorry for the basic question,
When I try to join my rental table and tp_rental table via the 'Rental_ID' column I get errors saying Error code: 1052 Column 'Rental_ID' in field list is ambiguous.

i can join rental and member tables no problem.

i am trying to print out a transaction report when a rental is completed (game is returned) that it will show rental ID, memberID, Due Date and Date Returned. 
I was using the below code but getting errors:

```
select Rental_ID,member_ID,completed,Date_Due,Date_Returned
from gamestoredb.rental
inner join gamestoredb.tp_rental
on rental.Rental_ID=tp_rental.Rental_ID
```

Comment: Give alias to the table names and refer those alias in the select list a.rental_ID..as Rental_ID is present in two tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rental_ID` is a column in each of the two tables you are joining so the server does not know which one you want `rental.Rental_ID` or `tp_rental.Rental_ID` even though in this particular they both would have the same value. Make which one you want explicit, for example:

```
select tp_rental.Rental_ID,member_ID,completed,Date_Due,Date_Returned
from gamestoredb.rental
inner join gamestoredb.tp_rental
on rental.Rental_ID=tp_rental.Rental_ID
```

Comment: You should make this a different question Gary